# check if data already exist

Tags: php, mysql, insert, get, explode

How can I check before storing in mysql wether in array 1 of the variables already exist in my database. if `$explode[$i]` exist go to next. if not exist run the code below!

Here is my code in php:

```
$request_user_ids = $_GET['req'];
     $explode = explode(',',$request_user_ids);
     for ($i=0; $i<count($explode);$i++){

  $result = mysql_query("
          INSERT INTO fbinvite (memberid, fbsender, fbempfang, regdatum, fbreturn) 
          VALUES(NULL, '".$userid."', '".$explode[$i]."', NOW(), '0')");
```

How can I do that there are no double inserts.

Comment: There is a mysql command for that, what you want is IGNORE, so you will ignore it if it already exists. If you want an Upsert or Merge, use ON DUPLICATE.

Comment: Thanks, most things are to easy to see. I did this with `IGNORE` cause "first come - first surf" but forgot setting fbempfang as `unique`

Comment: don't forget to sanitize input data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make the relevant set of attributes to be primary key or unique index of the table.

Then you have several options:

- blindly use [`INSERT IGNORE INTO fbinvite ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), if you simply want to ignore duplicated data OR
- check if entry exists: `SELECT memberid FROM fbinvite WHERE some_attr1 = $explode[...] AND some_attr2 = $explode[...]`; and continue appropriately:

  - if entry doesn't exist, insert it to the table: `INSERT INTO fbinvite ...`
  - if entry exists:

    - show message to the user OR
    - update existing entry: `UPDATE fbinvide ... WHERE ...`
  - insert OR update at once: [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: First part is the better way cause otherwise the query can be quite long when there are 30 variables. Thengo on with a simple `IF ($result){}`